# How to plot survival curves using survivalsvm in R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have read the usage of `svm` in survival analysis in R. Now I have implemented it by using the package `survivalsvm` in R. I have a dataset `df_acn`.

```
library(survivalsvm)
set.seed(2)
train <- sample(nrow(df_acn), 0.3*nrow(df_acn), replace = FALSE)
Train <- df_acn[train,]
Valid <- df_acn[-train,]
surv_model <- survivalsvm(Surv(Line_Tenure_In_Days, churn) ~ .-(Subscriber_Line_Id), Train,type = "regression", gamma.mu = 1,
                          opt.meth = "ipop", kernel = "add_kernel")

surv_model_prd <- predict( surv_model, Valid)
```

Now my question is how to plot the survival curve using the fitted model on the test set in R. I searched the internet but could not find much of help from there.

Comment: can you post data?

Comment: @Mike No sorry I cannot post data here. This is against the policy rules of my workplace. Please try it with any arbitrary survival data, say Lung data and try survivalsvm() package there.

Comment: That's not the way it works here. _You_ are the one who should "try it" with not-so-arbitrary data. If there are example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to plot a survival curve from an  *survivalsvm* object. Predicted values should be interpreted as ranks as described in fouodo et al. (2018). So appropriate performance measure when using *survivalsvm* is the *C-Index*.